# Setting up an ADF Clickhouse Linked Service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, clickhouse

I would like some help on how to setup a sink Clickhouse linked service on Azure (ADF).

I imagine that I'll need to use the ODBC connector however I'm stuck from there onwards. Does anyone has any instructions oh how I can setup this service?

When I go to new linked service I can't see a Clickhouse connector so ODBC seems my only option. JDBC is also not available!

Regards
Brian

Answer (score 0):

> Since there is no Clickhouse connector in ADF, you should consider to
> communicate with Clickhouse by writing your own code. Azure Functions
> or Custom activity in ADF can be used.